# Korean romanizer : it does not get everything romanized

Tags: javascript, transliteration

I'm working on a transliteration script (converting Korean syllables into the Latin alphabet).

The problem is that my script only accepts to romanize '갈라', '갈' or '라'. It doesn't get  '갈라라', '라갈', '갈 라', '라라', '갈갈', etc. to be converted.

Does anyone have a solution? I'd be really thankful.

```
<script>

var hangul_syllable_to_roman2 = {
'갈라' : 'galla',
}
var hangul_syllable_to_roman = {
'갈' : 'gal',
'라' : 'ra',
}

function transliteration_hangul_to_roman(syllable) {
    var roman2 = hangul_syllable_to_roman2[syllable];
    var roman = hangul_syllable_to_roman[syllable];
        if (roman2 || roman) {
        return roman2 || roman;
        }
        else {
        return syllable;
        }
}

function afficher(form2) {
    var testin = document.form2.entree.value;
                 document.form2.sortie.value=transliteration_hangul_to_roman(testin);
}

</script>

    <div>
        <FORM NAME="form2">
            <textarea name="entree" value="input"></textarea>      
            <input type="button" name="bouton" value="Convertir" onClick="afficher(form2)">
            <textarea name="sortie" value="output"></textarea>
        </FORM>         
    </div>
```

Comment: "doesn't want to" = ??

Comment: sorry for that English mistake.. I just mean "some strings don't get converted"

Answer (score 0):

You get only the two cases you defined because you are not looping over the entire input string.

Try this (untested!):

```
function transliteration_hangul_to_roman(syllable)
{
    var result = '', roman, roman2;
    while (syllable.length > 0)
    {
        roman2 = hangul_syllable_to_roman2[syllable.substr(0,2)];
        if (roman2)
        {
            result += roman2;
            syllable = syllable.substr(2);
        } else
        {
            roman = hangul_syllable_to_roman[syllable.substr(0,1)];
            if (roman)
                result += roman;
            else
                result += syllable.substr(0,1);
            syllable = syllable.substr(1);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```